# Memory efficient way to use sapply() in R

Tags: r, ram, sapply

I am trying to reduce the memory consumption of a piece of R code I have been working on. I am using the `peakRAM()` function to measure the maximum RAM used. It is a long code and there is a simple `sapply()` function at the end of it. I figured out that it is the `sapply()` part which is consuming the maximum memory. So I have written a small function `fun1()` imitating the objects and the `sapply()` function from that part of my code, which is as follows :

```
library(peakRAM)
fun1 <- function() {
  tm <- matrix(1, nrow = 300, ncol = 10)  #in the original code, the entries are different and nonzero
  print(object.size(tm))
  r <- sapply(1:20000, function(i) {
        colSums(tm[1:200,])  #in the original code, I am subsetting a 200 length vector which varies with i, stored in a list of length 20000
        })
  print(object.size(r))
  r
}

peakRAM(fun1())
```

If you run this in R, you get a `peakRAM()` consumption of around 330Mb. But you can see that the two objects `tm` and `r` are both of very small size (2Kb and 1.6Mb respectively) and if you look at the `peakRAM()` for computing a single `colSums(tm[1:200,])`, it is very small, like 0.1Mb. So it feels like, during `sapply()`, R is probably not getting rid of the memory while looping over `1:20000`. Otherwise, since a single `colSums(tm[1:200,])` takes very small memory, and all the objects associated are of small memory, the `sapply()` should have taken small memory.

In this regard, I already know that R has a `gc()` function which gets rid of unnecessary memory when needed and probably R is not clearing memory during `sapply()` which is resulting into this high memory consumption. If that is true, I would like to know if there is a way to get rid of this and complete the job without requiring this much extra memory? Note that, I do not wish to compromise on the run-time for doing that.

Comment: Every subset operation requires a memory allocation and garbage is not collected instantaneously. Note how memory usage drops considerably when you replace `tm[1:200, ]` with `tm`. It's hard to say whether there is a more efficient approach in R without more information about what you are trying to do, though you might consider replacing your `sapply` call with an equivalent `vapply` call. Ultimately, a task like this is best optimized in C...

Comment: @MikaelJagan Thanks for pointing it out. I had already noticed that using `tm` reduces the memory usage a lot, but unfortunately, I need that subsetting for my code. I have a list of length 20,000, whose i-th element is a vector of length about 200 and in the i-th iteration of `sapply()`, I am subsetting the rows in that vector, instead of the 1:200 in the example code. About using C, do you think an Rcpp implementation of the `sapply()` code here can solve the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is your function, modified to use `vapply` instead of `sapply` and `.colSums` instead of `colSums`:

```r
f1 <- function(x, l) {
    n <- ncol(x)
    FUN <- function(i) .colSums(x[i, , drop = FALSE], length(i), n)
    vapply(l, FUN, double(n), USE.NAMES = FALSE)
}
```

And here is a C implementation, made accessible to R via the `inline` package:

```r
sig <- c(x = "double", l = "list")
bod <- '
double *px = REAL(x);
R_xlen_t nx = XLENGTH(x);
int *d = INTEGER(getAttrib(x, R_DimSymbol));
int m = d[0];
int n = d[1];
R_xlen_t N = XLENGTH(l);

SEXP res = PROTECT(allocMatrix(REALSXP, n, N));
double *pres = REAL(res);

SEXP index;
R_xlen_t nindex;
int *pindex;
double sum;

for (R_xlen_t i = 0, rpos = 0; i < N; ++i)
{
    index = VECTOR_ELT(l, i);
    nindex = XLENGTH(index);
    pindex = INTEGER(index);
    for (R_xlen_t xpos = 0; xpos < nx; xpos += m, ++rpos)
    {
        sum = 0.0;
        for (R_xlen_t k = 0; k < nindex; ++k)
        {
            sum += px[xpos + pindex[k] - 1];
        }
        pres[rpos] = sum;
    }
}
UNPROTECT(1);
return res;
'
f2 <- inline::cfunction(sig, bod, language = "C")
```

The C code here is quite minimal, so I have stuck to the [R API](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#The-R-API). You can write equivalent C++ code using the [`Rcpp` API](https://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp.html), which you might find more approachable.

Here is a test showing that `f1` and `f2` give identical results:

```r
set.seed(1L)
m <- 300L
n <- 10L
x <- matrix(rnorm(m * n), m, n)
l <- replicate(2e+04, sample(m, size = 200L, replace = TRUE), simplify = FALSE)
identical(f1(x, l), f2(x, l))
## [1] TRUE
```

And here is the result of profiling `f1(x, l)` and `f2(x, l)` on my machine:

```r
gc(FALSE)
Rprof("f.out", interval = 1e-05, memory.profiling = TRUE)
f1(x, l)
f2(x, l)
Rprof(NULL)
summaryRprof("f.out", memory = "both")[["by.total"]][c("\"f1\"", "\"f2\""), c("total.time", "mem.total")]
```

```
     total.time mem.total
"f1"      0.119     344.4
"f2"      0.001       1.5
```

The `f1` call takes 0.119 seconds and consumes 344.4 MiB of memory. The `f2` call takes 0.001 seconds and consumes 1.5 MiB of memory—which is more or less the size of the return value. (Interpret these results with care: `Rprof` comes with a number of [caveats](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Tidying-and-profiling-R-code).)

Comment: Package `inline` lives!  Old-school.  Wow :)  Obvious upvote!  (You may like one of my other packages too: `tidyCpp` -- a (very) lightweight C++ wrapper around the R headers with a bit more sanity from C++.)

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel I take my coffee black. :-)